# Copy a cell for x times in other cells

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

I have some information in the following cells: H3,H4 and H5. Exactly: H3 contains letter *a*, H4 contains *b* and H5 contains *c*. Now I would like to put the content of each these cells as follows:

```
C11=a,C12=a,C13=a,C14=a,C15=a,C16=a. 

C17=b,C18=b,C19=b,C20=b,C21=b,C22=b. 

C23=b, C24=c,C25=c,C26=c,C27=c,C28=c.
```

It can be observe that we have a step of 6.

I have tried the following code:

```
For s = 0 To 17
Cells(s + 11, 3).Value = Cells(CInt(3 + (s / 6)), 8)
Next
```

My problem is, that the  cells are not filled in a correct way and also C26, C27, C28 remain empty.

Thanks!

Comment: There are no such things as cells in Microsoft Access. Are you sure you didn't mean to tag this [tag:excel-vba]?

Comment: Are you using Excel or Access?

Comment: Have you debugged your code to see how it works?

Comment: I'm using excel.

Comment: Why only **5** c's and **7** b's ?

Comment: It is my mistake. It is.the same number: 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CInt
```

performs a rounding and not a truncating of the integer

you should use Int

```
For s = 0 To 17
Cells(s + 11, 3).Value = Cells(Int(3 + (s / 6)), 8)
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Run it like this:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim s   As Long

    For s = 0 To 17
        Debug.Print Cells(s + 11, 3).Address
        Debug.Print Cells(CInt(3 + (s / 6)), 8).Address
        Cells(s + 11, 3).Value = Cells(CInt(3 + (s / 6)), 8)
    Next s

End Sub
```

Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> and see the printed addresses in the immediate window.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve same result without VBA.

In cell C11 put following formula and copy down to get the results you need

`=INDEX($H$3:$H$5,CEILING(ROWS($C$11:C11)/6,1))`